# why onPanelCosed is not called when the options menu is dismissed?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm setting up the overflow button as below in the subclass of **AppCompatActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // For Hamburger menu
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar?.overflowIcon =
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_hamberger_menu, null)
}

// Menu icons are inflated just as they were with actionbar
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    Log.e("Menu", "onCreateOptionsMenu")
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.rms_patrol_menu, menu)
    if (menu is MenuBuilder) {
        menu.setOptionalIconsVisible(true)
    }
    return true
}

override fun onMenuOpened(featureId: Int, menu: Menu): Boolean {
    toolbar?.overflowIcon =
        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_about, null)
    if ( featureId == AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR) {
        Log.e("Menu", "onMenuOpened")
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu)
}

override fun onPanelClosed(featureId: Int, menu: Menu) {

    Log.e("Menu", "onPanelClosed")
    super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu)
}
```

the **onMenuOpened** is called each time the menus are shown, but the **onPanelClosed** is never called when dismiss the menus. Is there anything wrong/missing for the **onPanelClosed**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ToolBarActionBar` class have this code

```
    @Override
    public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menu) {
        if (mWindowCallback != null) {
            if (mDecorToolbar.isOverflowMenuShowing()) {
                mWindowCallback.onPanelClosed(AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR, menu);
            } else if (mWindowCallback.onPreparePanel(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL,
                    null, menu)) {
                mWindowCallback.onMenuOpened(AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR, menu);
            }
        }
    }
```

first of all the activity must support `FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR`

remove layout toolbar

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menu?:return false
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_operate, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onMenuOpened(featureId: Int, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        Log.e("Menu", "onMenuOpened")
        return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu)
    }

    override fun onPanelClosed(featureId: Int, menu: Menu) {
        Log.e("Menu", "onPanelClosed")
        super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu)
    }

}
```

and use action bar

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!--<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>-->
</style>
```

then you can view the log like this

```
2019-12-02 16:53:17.600 14963-14963/ E/Menu: onMenuOpened
2019-12-02 16:53:20.212 14963-14963/ E/Menu: onPanelClosed
```

we can custom action over by

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!--<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomOverFlow</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomOverFlow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/ic_menu_add</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">"Lala"</item>
</style>
```

This is demo layout `R.layout.activity_main`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

without `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`
if you want use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` 
[see offical developer doc](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)

I change layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        >
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World!"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!--<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomOverFlow</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomOverFlow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/ic_menu_add</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">"Lala"</item>
</style>


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menu?:return false
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_operate, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onMenuOpened(featureId: Int, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        Log.e("Menu", "onMenuOpened")
        return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu)
    }

    override fun onPanelClosed(featureId: Int, menu: Menu) {
        Log.e("Menu", "onPanelClosed")
        super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu)
    }

}
```

then `onPanelClosed` can call

Comment: in this way, is there any chance to customise the overflowIcon? Why i need to know options are on/off is to change the overflowIcon accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you post your activity_main also? somehow my layout cannot show the toolbar in this way

Comment: It use default action bar

Comment: to use default action bar, we need specify in the layout?